# <a> Tags shown on

Tags: bug, status-completed

https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/badges/84/informed

The HTML `<a>` Tag is shown instead of a link...

Edit: While writing this post it occured to me, that this might not be the only place where this bug can be found and - surprise - there is more:

https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/badges

Of course I might have missed something. Feel free to add similar sites into my report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, see this [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191342/several-badge-descriptions-contain-raw-html) post for details.

Comment: ah perfect, sorry for the double post